# Backbone.js template: Render HTML from model?

Tags: html, json, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I have an API that return HTML serialized in JSON accessed through a REST API. When I try to render the HTML from the API response, the HTML code is display as such:
`<p>Hello this is a response!</p>`, instead of as:

Hello this is a response!

Is there any way to work around this?

Also, what are the potential security issues with doing this and actually render the HTML?

Best regards and help is much appreciated. :)

EDIT: Here are my models and my template. Sufficient to say, I'm new to Backbone.js, and this is mostly based on the Todos example.

Views:

```
app.DataView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    template: _.template($("#data-template").html()),
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#htmldataapp",
    initialize: function() {
        app.datamodels.on('reset', this.addAll, this);
        app.datamodels.fetch();
        this.render();
    },
    addOne: function(datamodel) {
        var view = new app.DataView({model: datamodel});
        $('#data-list').append(view.render().el);
    },
    addAll: function() {
        this.$('#data-list').html('');
        app.datamodels.each(this.addOne, this);
    }
});
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="data-template">
    <%= data %>
</script>
```

Comment: Right now using the Underscore.js templating system. I'm simply using a template that looks like this: `<script type="text/template" id="data-template"><p><%= data %></p></script>`.

Comment: please show us the code of your backbone view, the template and data string you get from the API...

Comment: I updated the original post with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You state that your api sends you HTML already?

So could it be that the data you get back is like  `<p>Hello this is a response!</p>`, thus including the HTML tags?

If you would have underscore render this string in a template, it's no surprise you actually get the HTML tags to display.

Look at the generated source of the page, is the string  `Hello this is a response!` wrapped in double `<p>` elements?

I would suggest changing your API in such a way that it returns data only (i.e. the string without the HTML), and have your HTML rendering be done by the underscore template engine.

Hope it helps!

EDIT:

I think you were using the underscore template function to often, causing the data to be rendered as a string.

Please [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jorrebor/avm3f/) for a sample setup how I think you should setup your app

Comment: Yes, the response includes HTML tags. The text is not wrapped in double `<p>` elements in the generated source code, it looks like "regular" HTML. 

This is for a scenario where the formatting is predetermined by the back-end. Therefore it's not possible to let Underscore handle the HTML.

Comment: Hi, i have added a fiddle, see my edit. I think you were actually on the right track. But the template you first used contained p tag's and the data itself as well... I think you really should seperate your tags and content. Good luck!